# qobject_cast always returns NULL?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to cast from QObject* to QSlider* with **qobject_cast**, but through debugging, the variable `cObj` is not NULL, but `vNumSlider` is NULL.

here is some related snippet in .cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QQmlComponent component(&engine,QUrl(QStringLiteral(MAIN_FORM)));
    QObject *obj = component.create();
    QObject *cObj = obj->findChild<QObject*>("vNumSlider");
    QSlider *vNumSlider = qobject_cast<QSlider*>(cObj);
    delete obj;
    return app.exec();
}
```

and .qml

```
Slider {
    id: vNumSlider
    objectName: "vNumSlider"
    maximumValue: 130
    x: 85
    y: 12
}
```

Comment: How sure are you that a qml slider is actually a QSlider? I know that a QSlider is not a qml slider, but other way might be true. Check the docs or even the source of the qml slider to make sure

Comment: QSlider is a widget, a QtQuick slider isn't, they have nothing in common.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld was right!!  I was misled by the class name

Comment: Visual qml item should be cast to QQuickItem